# How To Keep Turtle From Overwriting Previous Shape

Tags: python, user-interface, shapes, turtle-graphics, overwrite

I am trying to create multiple shapes in Turtle but it overwrites the previous shape that I created. For Example:

```
import turtle
#Setting Up Turtle:
ws = turtle.Screen()
ws.bgcolor("White")
ws.title("Test")
skk = turtle.Turtle()

def createrect(objname, y):
        #This creates a rectangle.

        #The Rectangle Coordinates:
        rectcoords = ((-20, y), (20, 10), (-20, -10), (20, -10))

        #Registering The Rectangle (In my program, I have a unique name registered to each rectangle I create, but for demonstration I will make the object name a Function Parameter.)
        ws.register_shape(objname, rectcoords)

        #Creates The Shape of the Rectangle:
        turtle.shape(objname)
        turtle.fillcolor("gray")


#I have two Rectangles that I create with the Function above, however the second shape over-rides the first one. 

#I made the "y" parameter to show the difference between the first rectangle and second rectangle :p

createrect("obj1", 500)
input("Rectangle 1: ")
createrect("obj2", 10)
input("Rectangle 2: Notice that the first Rectangle was deleted.")
```

I have two Rectangles that I create with the Function above, however the second shape over-rides the first one. How can I keep both shapes?
Note: I initially was going to make the rectangles manually until I realized that the "shape" Function existed (which I needed to color my rectangles). Does it pertain to using the up() and down() Turtle Functions? I don't even think I need to use those Functions while using the "shape" Function but I am not an expert.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is `turtle.stamp()`.

The problem seems to be you're confusing what the turtle cursor looks like and what the turtle cursor has drawn.  You're only changing what the cursor looks like, you haven't drawn anything.  By invoking `turtle.stamp()`, you cause what the turtle looks like to be stamped onto the page at the current turtle position:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def createrect(cursor_name, y):
    # This creates a rectangle.

    # The Rectangle Coordinates:
    rectcoords = ((-20, y), (20, 10), (-20, -10), (20, -10))

    # Registering The Rectangle (In my program, I have a unique name registered to each
    # rectangle I create, but for demonstration I make the object name a function parameter.)
    screen.register_shape(cursor_name, rectcoords)

    # Creates The Shape of the Rectangle:
    turtle.shape(cursor_name)
    turtle.stamp()

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.fillcolor('gray')

# "y" parameter shows difference between the first rectangle and second rectangle

createrect('obj1', 50)
input("Rectangle 1: (return to continue) ")

createrect('obj2', 10)
input("Rectangle 2: (return to continue) ")
```